# IF null or empty set 0 LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, model-view-controller

i I try to have this table show value 0 if there are no records to count empty or null, I am counting equal strings, my string being "sm_red".

MVC LinQ .NET Framework 4.5

```
List<string> trae = new List<string>();
            trae = db.SM_App.Where(x => x.sm_canal.ToString() == "EVERYTHING").Select(x => x.sm_categoria).Distinct().ToList();

var query = (from a in trae
             join b in db.SM_App on a equals b.sm_categoria
             where b.sm_canal == "EVERYGHINT" && b.sm_fecha > sDate && b.sm_fecha < fDate
             group b by b.sm_categoria into g
             select new
             {
             Categoria = g.Key,
             Facebook = g.Count(x => x.sm_red == "Facebook"),
             Twitter = g.Count(x => x.sm_red == "Twitter"),
             Instagram = g.Count(x => x.sm_red == "Instagram") 
             }).Distinct().ToList();
```

UPDATE 13/08/2019

I try this, but return "Count = 0", and in the view return nothing

```
var query = (from a in trae
          join b in db.SM_App on a equals b.sm_categoria into grp
          from c in grp.DefaultIfEmpty()
          where c.sm_canal == "EVERY" && c.sm_fecha > sDate && c.sm_fecha < fDate       
          group c by c.sm_categoria into g
          select new 
          {
            Categoria = g.Key,
            Facebook = g.Count(x => x.sm_red == "Facebook").ToString() == "" ? Convert.ToInt32(g.Key) : 0,
            Twitter = g.Count(x => x.sm_red == "Twitter").ToString() == "" ? Convert.ToInt32(g.Key) : 0,
            Instagram = g.Count(x => x.sm_red == "Instagram").ToString() == "" ? Convert.ToInt32(g.Key) : 0
           }).Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: Assuming `g` is from a `groupby`, it is impossible for `g` to be empty or null, so your `Count` will return zero when `g` has no members matching the condition. `Count` returns zero for an empty `IEnumerable` already.

Comment: OK, update the question with the whole context

Comment: Which data access library (Entity Framework?) and which version?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve. Also, you do show code, but you don't tell why it (apparently) fails.

Comment: Entity Framework

Comment: The code does not really fail, it returns the values correctly as long as they exist, if the records do not exist, nothing returns, and I try that if it does not exist, put 0

Comment: *in the view return nothing* -- Which view? Why don't you show an example result of `query` just as it is, without any view involved. Maybe then we can begin to understand what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

If your entire query returns zero records, then you will have zero records in your result. If you want a record with `0`s in it, you must use `DefaultIfEmpty()`:

```
var query = (from a in trae
             join b in db.SM_App on a equals b.sm_categoria
             where b.sm_canal == "EVERYGHINT" && b.sm_fecha > sDate && b.sm_fecha < fDate
             group b by b.sm_categoria into g
             select new {
                 Categoria = g.Key,
                 Facebook = g.Count(x => x.sm_red == "Facebook"),
                 Twitter = g.Count(x => x.sm_red == "Twitter"),
                 Instagram = g.Count(x => x.sm_red == "Instagram") 
             }).Distinct()
               .DefaultIfEmpty(new {
                   Categoria = default(string),
                   Facebook = 0,
                   Twitter = 0,
                   Instagram = 0 
               })
               .ToList();
```

I didn't know what `Categoria` you expected in that case, or its type, so I just assumed string and `default(string)` which is `null`.

Comment: Hi NetMage, I TRY BUT IT MAKES MISTAKE

Comment: If this is causing an error, what is it? Now that you say you are using EF, probably a can't be translated error, in which case move the `DefaultIfEmpty` to after the `ToList`.

Comment: Retunrs Empty :/

Comment: @Ransomware0 what does that mean?